# Why the camera intent do not return after photo taken

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am trying to write a function that allow the user select to open a camera , then when the user take one photo, it return , get the scaled photo and set that bitmap on the imageView. The problem is either the default camera or other camera apps on the market will not fire the return case after I take a pic ,  how to fix that ? Thanks

Take picture button:

```
takePic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                File tempFile;
                try {
                    tempFile = File.createTempFile("my_app", ".jpg");
                    fileName = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }           
        });
```

After intent result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_GET_IMAGE_ALBUM && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(this, SharePicForm.class);
            shareIntent.putExtra("photo", Utility.getImagePath(selectedImage,this));
            startActivity(shareIntent);
        } else if ( requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("test1","return");
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(this, SharePicForm.class);
            shareIntent.putExtra("photo", data.getStringExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));
            startActivity(shareIntent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: So whats happening, is the app crashing on return?

Comment: Do you have anything shown in Log Cat?

Comment: Not crash nothing happen